# Find and replace by locating column and row using Python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a dataframe where I would like to find a specific value in a row and column and replace it with a blank.  I would like to replace the value in the ['type'] column in the row that contains 'CC'

**Data**

```
ID date      type
AA 1/1/2022  Ok
BB 2/1/2022  Hi
CC 2/1/2022  Hi
```

**Desired**

```
ID date      type
AA 1/1/2022  Ok
BB 2/1/2022  Hi
CC 2/1/2022
```

**Doing**

```
df['type'] = df['type'].str.replace('Hi','')
```

However this is removing all values in the column. Any suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: `df.loc[df['type'].eq('Hi') & df['ID'].eq('CC'), 'type'] = ''`

Comment: `mask = (df['ID'] == 'CC')` and `df.loc[mask, 'type'] = df.loc[mask, 'type'].str.replace('Hi','')`